# Не могу добавить кнопки в Trix редакторе в RoR проекте

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

Не могу добавить нужные мне кнопки (текст слева, по центру, справа) на тулбар редактора Trix в RoR проекте.
Перечитал кучу информации, но так добавить и не получилось.

Пробовал добавить в файлик JS следующее:

```
Trix.config.textAttributes.sup = { tagName: "sup", inheritable: true }
Trix.config.textAttributes.sub = { tagName: "sub", inheritable: true }

addEventListener("trix-initialize", function(event) {
  var buttonHTML, buttonGroup
  buttonHTML  = '<button type="button" data-trix-attribute="sup"><sup>SUP</sup></button>'
  buttonHTML += '<button type="button" data-trix-attribute="sub"><sub>SUB</sub></button>'
  buttonGroup = event.target.toolbarElement.querySelector(".button_group.text_tools")
  buttonGroup.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", buttonHTML)
})
```

Я не могу понять, что мне нужно ещё добавить в HTML код, чтобы было отображение этих кнопок, так как во view-файле я пишу только `trix-editor` и всё

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста к вопросу ваш код, в котором "не получилось"

Comment: В какой JS файл вы это добавляете? Он точно у вас вызывается? `addEventListener` срабатывает? Турболинки есть в проекте?

Comment: Добавляю в файл app/assets/javascripts/application.js